# how to trigger dajaxice.core.js to be updated with ajax.py

Tags: django, dajaxice

I am using django-dajaxice, and after I tried the example, the file of `dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js` has loaded some functions from `myapp/ajax.py`

But the strange part is that, if I update this ajax.py in myapp folder, the js file is not updated with it, no matter I add a function or change the name of it, or delete any function in ajax.py.

The strange thing is that only sayhello works, ANY other function name doesn't work. Is it anything related with .pyc files? I deleted all the pyc files and got the same error.

Or in Python3, I shouldn't use dajaxice? But why sayhello works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I ended up `touch`-ing the `__init__.py` in the folder that contains `ajax.py`. That solved my issue.

Are you loading your function using the `{% dajaxice_js %}` (or similar) function, or are you loading it through some other method? The js is dynamically generated, which is loaded by the template.

Here's a useful link.

http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#create-your-first-ajax-function

Comment: It works! And I used the touch from cygwin on my Windows, and an alternative to use touch on windows would be at here, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command)